# Print all words and their count

Tags: c, hashtable

I'm to print all words and their count of a text file. When it reads the same word a second time it outputs the number zero. I can't figure out how to output the correct value. For example, if it found "and" it would print "and: 1" but when it finds "and" again it prints "and: 0".

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "hashMap.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]){
   char* word;
   int *value = 0;
   const char* filename;
   struct hashMap *hashTable;   
   int tableSize = 10;
   clock_t timer;
   FILE *fileptr;   
   if(argc == 2)
      filename = argv[1];
   else
      filename = "input1.txt"; /*specify your input text file here*/
   printf("opening file: %s\n", filename);
   fileptr = fopen(filename, "r");
   if(fileptr != 0){
      printf("Open Successfull!\n");
   }
   else{
      printf("Failed to open!\n");
   }
   timer = clock();
   hashTable = createMap(tableSize);       
   /*... concordance code goes here ...*/
   while(1){
      word = getWord(fileptr);
      if(word == NULL){
     break;
      }
      value = (int*)atMap(hashTable, word);
      if(value != NULL){
     value++;
      }
      else{
     value = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
     *value = 1;
     insertMap(hashTable, word, value);
      }
      printf("%s:%d\n", word, *value);
   }
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting this hash table implementation?

Answer (score 0):

The value you're fetching from the hashtable is a pointer to a block of memory with a single integer. You then increment the pointer, which makes it point to uninitialized memory, which just happens to have a zero in it. You probably want to increment the integer value, not the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Value is a pointer to an int. You don't want to increment the pointer, but rather increment the int it points to. Change value++ to (*value)++.